# get the size of the mouse wheel on the screen

Tags: java

Hello I am practicing with the mousewheel event in Java, therefore I made a circel that grows and shrimps when the mousewheel is moved. now I also want to show the size of the "MousWheel" on the screen next to the mouse pointer. Can anyone show me an example of how to do this?

this is what I got now.

```
public class MouseWheelPanel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener {

private int grootte = 50;

public MouseWheelPanel() {
    this.addMouseWheelListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent( g );
    g.setColor( Color.YELLOW ); 
    g.fillOval( 10, 10, grootte, grootte );
}


public void mouseWheelMoved( MouseWheelEvent e ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String 
    grootte += e.getWheelRotation();
    repaint(); 
}

}
```

Comment: `g.drawString(arguments)` Just look up that method in the Graphics api.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are also interested in positioning the text.  Look up [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html).  This will center the size string in the circle.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(10, 10, grootte, grootte);

    String str = ""+grootte;
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    Rectangle2D strBounds = fm.getStringBounds(str, g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(str, 10 + grootte/2 - (int)strBounds.getWidth()/2, 10 + grootte/2 + (int)strBounds.getHeight()/2);
}
```